# Dhtmlx Gannt Chart not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dhtmlx

I'm using CodeIgniter and DHTMLX to build gannt charts in my system. I have followed the tutorial in the website accordingly. But the chart doesn't display on the web page. I'm new to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code in controller

```
    <?php
use codebase/connector/GanttConnector;

class Gantt extends CI_Controller {                 
   public function index(){  
        $admindata["main_content"] = 'GanttView';
        $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard_main/template',$admindata);                         
    }

    public function data(){                                                     
        $this->load->database(); // data feed                                   

        $controller = new GanttConnector($this->db, "PHPCI");                   
        $controller->render_links("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type");   
        $controller->render_table(                                              
            "gantt_tasks",                                                      
            "id",                                                               
            "start_date,duration,text,progress,parent"                             
       );                                                                       
    }
}                                                                                          

?>
```

Here's the view

```
<div id="gantt_here" style='width:100%; height:250px;'></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    gantt.init("gantt_here", new Date(2010,7,1), new Date(2010,8,1));
    // refers to the 'data' action that we will create in the next substep 
    gantt.load("./gantt/data", "xml");
    // refers to the 'data' action as well
    var dp = new dataProcessor("./gantt/data");
    dp.init(gantt);
</script>
```

I am also confused about the "use" key word in

```
use codebase/connector/GanttConnector;
```

Any help regarding the matter? Thanks.